# Dapper. IoC, Testing and Agatha

Tags: testing, inversion-of-control, dapper, agatha-rrsl

On a MVC 3 project I am using EF4, IoC and Agatha-RRSL as my service layer.

Fortunately, this week I found Dapper and I am moving from EF4 to Dapper!

Usually I inject a Generic Repository in my Agatha Request Handlers ...

But how should I use Dapper?

1) Should I inject a IDbConnection in the Agatha Handler?
   Then inside the handler I use it with Dapper Query or Dapper Execute?
   Is this testable? And what about mocking?

2) Should I create a generic repository for Dapper?
   Maybe the repository would be something like:

```
public class Repository {

  private IDbConnection _connection;

  public Repository(IDbConnection connection) {
    _connection = connection;
  } // Repository

  public Int32 Execute(String sql, dynamic param = null) {
    return _connection.Execute(sql, param); 
  } // Execute

  // Query code   
}
```

And the IDbConnection would be injected here.

And the repository would be injected inside the handlers.

Not sure how to test this ...

3) Should I just place all my code inside the handler?

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
 connection.Execute(@"insert Roles(Name) values (@name)", new { name = "Role" }); 
}
```

But what about testing?

4) I have realize that Dapper uses static methods.
   Doesn't this raise some memory problems?

Sorry for so many questions ... I am trying to make this right.

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: For inserting records, you might also want to look at Dapper-Rainbow. (Available on NuGet). PS: 3) - dapper recuires an open connection.

Comment: Yes, I just found Dapper-Rainbow ... But I am considering in breaking that code in 3: Database which holds the connection, Session of the transations and Repository for the methods. What do you think? I think it is better for testing. What do you think? I will post my code here ...

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but I want to point out that your repository implementation is really a "data access object".  Repositories deal with whole aggregates, ie. a group of things that belong together.  Ideally your interface should only accept and return objects of the aggregate root type (for example, a `Repository<User>` may have methods `void Update(User user) {}` or `IEnumerable<User> Find(...) {}`).

Usage or existence of any persistence mechanism is an implementation detail and would not typically belong in a repository interface, nor would it speak SQL.